# How to add the current git commit hash as an environment variable in a Digital Ocean app

Tags: git, environment-variables, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I have an app on Digital Ocean, and I want to be able to access the current git commit from the app code as an environment variable. From reading [this help page](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#component-specific-variables), it looks like I should be able to set a variable to `${COMMIT_HASH}`, but when I tried that it was just set to the literal string `${COMMIT_HASH}`. Why is Digital Ocean not replacing it with the actual hash of the commit it's building my app from?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You probably want `${_self.COMMIT_HASH}`

Longer answer:

In the list of bindable names, it just says `${COMMIT_HASH}` but if you look at the top of that section it says

> Component specific variables need to be prefixed by the component name, for example `${my-service.BINDABLE_NAME}`. The `_self` prefix can be used to reference the current component, for example `${_self.BINDABLE_NAME}`.

I think the list below that should really say `${(componentName).PRIVATE_DOMAIN}`, `${(componentName).PRIVATE_URL}`, etc. so that people who are skimming through the docs quickly aren't misled.